# How to put array of elements into a form and not manually?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

How to make a form from an array of items retrieved from a database, and puts each of those elements into the form?

Right now I can't get the items to appear in the form. It's empty.

Here is what I am trying but no luck.

**JS file**:

```
function input(items) {
    var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.items.length; i++) {
        arr.push(this.state.items[i].name)
      }
      arr.forEach(function(item) {
        var source = document.getElementById("cowNames[]")
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = item;
        source.append(option, source[0])
    });
};
```

**HTML**:

```
<form name="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
        Find Item:
        <select>
            <option id="cowNames[]" className="items">
            </option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="View Info" />
</form>
```

In conclusion, I want to make this but showing form options already retrieved from a database and not have to manually add them.

Comment: Are you using React? If yes, can you add the entire component?

Answer (score 1):

Each `<option>` needs to be appended to the `<select>` element. A more idiomatic solution in React would be:

```
// Assuming `optionsArr` contains your option values
<form name="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <label>
    Find Item:
    <select>
      {optionsArr.map((optionName) => (
        <option value={optionName}>{optionName}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="View Info" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you so much! Migraine has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the options to the `<select>` element. E.g.

```js
    var arr =  ['dexter','aberdeen','hereford']
      arr.forEach(function(item) {
        var source = document.getElementById("cowNames[]")
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.classList.add("items");
        option.text = item;
        source.append(option, source[0])
        })
```

```html
      <form name="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Find Item:
          <select id="cowNames[]">

          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="View Info" />
      </form>
```

Comment: Just want to say that, if OP is using React this can be done in a far better way

Comment: @RameshReddy why not post as another answer? I'm not a react user, so would like to understand how it would be better...

Comment: We don't need to query for elements in this case. Look at juliomalves' answer.

Comment: @RameshReddy, thanks, that is quite neat!